# How to use Office UI Fabric Callout in SPFx WebParts?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, best-practices, typescript, fabric

I try to use a good pattern to use the `Callout`, for instance when hovering over a `Persona` element. Currently I do the following:

- `_clientPersonaElement` is a reference to the Element the `Callout` uses as location: `Callout.target`
- `state.clientCalloutVisible` is set by `_onShowClientCallout` to show the `Callout`. It is reset by `_onClientCalloutDismiss`

Here the code:

```
export default class ILoggerListItem extends React.Component<IILoggerListItemProps,IILoggerListItemState> {
    private _clientPersonaElement: HTMLElement;

    constructor(props: IILoggerListItemProps) {
        super(props);

        this._onShowClientCallout = this._onShowClientCallout.bind(this);
        this._onClientCalloutDismiss = this._onClientCalloutDismiss.bind(this);

        this.state = {
          clientCalloutVisible: false
        };
    }

    private _onShowClientCallout(person: IInteractionLogPerson, event: React.MouseEvent<Persona>) {
        if(! this.state.clientCalloutVisible)
        {
            this.setState(
            { 
                clientCalloutVisible: true,
            });
        }
    }

    private _onClientCalloutDismiss() {
        if( this.state.clientCalloutVisible)
        {
            this.setState({
                clientCalloutVisible: false
            });
        }
    }
```

My render looks like:

```
public render(): JSX.Element {

return (
  <div
    role='row'
    className={ classILoggerItem }
    data-is-focusable={ true } >
    <FocusZone direction={ FocusZoneDirection.horizontal }>
      <div className={ css(styles.itemTaskRow, 'ms-Grid-row') }>

        <div className= {css( 'ms-Grid-col', 'ms-u-sm4')}
          ref={ (targetElement) => this._clientPersonaElement = targetElement } >
          <Persona 
            onMouseOver= {(event) => this._onShowClientCallout(person, event)}
            size= { PersonaSize.regular }
            imageUrl= { person.Picture }
            primaryText= { person.Title }
            secondaryText= { person.MobilePhone }
          />
        </div>

      </div>
    </FocusZone>
    { this.state.clientCalloutVisible && (
      <Callout
        className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCallout ) }
        gapSpace={ 0 }
        onDismiss={ this._onClientCalloutDismiss }
        target={this._clientPersonaElement}
        setInitialFocus={ true }
      >
        <div className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCalloutHeader) }>
          <p className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCalloutTitle, 'ms-font-l') }>
            { this.props.item.Client.Title }
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCalloutInner) }>
          <div className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCalloutContent) }>
            <p className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCalloutSubText, 'ms-font-m') }>
              { this.props.item.Client.MobilePhone } <br />
              { this.props.item.Client.EMail }
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCalloutActions) }>
            <Link className={ css(styles.iLoggerClientCalloutLink) } href='http://microsoft.com'>Go to profile</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Callout>
    ) }
  </div>
);
}
```

I wrap the `Persona` element in a `Div` element, so I can get a reference used for the `target` property of the `Callout`:

I couldn't get `ref=..` on the `PersonA` to work, because it's not an `HtmlElement`.

- `target` of the `Callout` can be a `MouseEvent`, but I couldn't figure out, how to get the `Persona.onMouseOver` as a `MouseEvent`.
- `target` can be *a querySelector string of a valid HTMLElement* . Is it possible to reference the `Persona` element via a querySelector?

Is this a good pattern with the additional div element and `ref=..` ? Or would using `MouseEvent` or `querySelector` better?

Every feedback is valued and appreciated :-)

Comment: Is there any error logs on your browser console? Start by putting a debugger on _onShowClientCallout function and check if it is invoking or not.

Comment: The above code is working. I don't know how to use the `MouseEvent` for the `Callout.target`. I tried using the `React.MouseEvent<Persona>` passed to the `onMouseEnter` handler, but it failed, because it is not of type `MouseEvent`. Is the `<div>` wrapper the best approach for this?

Comment: Yes, as a workaround and for testing purpose attaching it to wrapper div mouse event is good approach.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that how to specify the target for a Callout control is not very well documented.  In my case, I was trying to display a callout when a command button was clicked in a Command Bar control.  I wanted the callout to popup at the location of the clicked command button and so couldn't just wrap the control in a container div and create a react ref for that.

However, I was able to trap the onClick event for the command button and throw it into an IPoint object.

```
private mouseClickPoint : IPoint;

private onClickOpenCallout = (ev?: any, item?: IContextualMenuItem) : boolean | void  => {
    this.mouseClickPoint = {x: ev.clientX, y: ev.clientY};
}
```

Note that I needed to cast the event to 'any', in order to access the clientX and clientY properties.  You can then use this point as the target in the Callout control.

```
<Callout target={this.mouseClickPoint}>
    {/* payload goes here */}
</Callout>;
```